# String List Used to reference String in Class

Tags: apex, list, compile-error

I am trying to use a string list and it's values to represent members of a class, but it is taking the variable literally and returns that the variable does not exist. Is it possible to reference an external class using local variables like this?

`getData.accounts[0]` returns the account class from `dataHere` no problem, but the error comes up reference that keyList is not a variable.

Data Class:

```
    public class dataHere {  
        public List<Accounts> accounts;


    public class Accounts {
        public String accountNumber;
    }
}
```

Handling Class:

```
    public class handleHere {  
        public List<String> keyList = new List<String>();
        dataHere getData = dataHere.Class;
        keyList.add('accountNumber');
        system.debug(getData.accounts[0].(keyList[0]));
    }
```

**EDIT**:
The exact error I receive is:

> Variable does not exist: keyList at line 245 column 60.

I know that `keyList` does not exist in `getData.account`, but in the same class that I am calling `keyList` from (`dataHere`), I have defined it as a string list that I want to use to reference the strings in `getData.account`.

If `getData.account[0].accountNumber` exists, why doesn't `getData.account[0].keyList[0]` exist when `keyList[0]` has been defined as the string `'accountNumber'`?

Comment: There are an awful lot of reasons this code won't compile. Please include any and all error messages you get here ***verbatim***. Please **[edit]** your post to include any such clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax would require something like java.lang.reflect. Unfortunately, that doesn't in Apex Code. As such, there's no direct way to access a field dynamically that way (at least for non-SObject types).

If you really want dynamic access to the members, I'd suggest using a Map instead:

```
public class dataHere {  
    public List<Map<String,Object>> accounts;
}
```